# Format string dynamically

Tags: python, string

If I want to make my formatted string dynamically adjustable, I can change the following code from

```
print '%20s : %20s' % ("Python", "Very Good")
```

to

```
width = 20
print ('%' + str(width) + 's : %' + str(width) + 's') % ("Python", "Very Good")
```

However, it seems that string concatenation is cumbersome here. Any other way to simplify things?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can fetch the padding value from the argument list:

```
print '%*s : %*s' % (20, "Python", 20, "Very Good")
```

You can even insert the padding values dynamically:

```
width = 20
args = ("Python", "Very Good")
padded_args = zip([width] * len(args), args)
# Flatten the padded argument list.
print "%*s : %*s" % tuple([item for list in padded_args for item in list])
```

Answer (score 125):

You can do this using the [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) method.

```
>>> width = 20
>>> print("{:>{width}} : {:>{width}}".format("Python", "Very Good", width=width))
              Python :            Very Good
```

Starting from Python 3.6 you can use [`f-string`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals) to do this:

```
In [579]: lang = 'Python'

In [580]: adj = 'Very Good'

In [581]: width = 20

In [582]: f'{lang:>{width}}: {adj:>{width}}'
Out[582]: '              Python:            Very Good'
```

Comment: Can we align it to left as well?

Comment: [format-specification](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) @alper

Answer (score 34):

For those who want to do the same thing with python 3.6+ and [f-Strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) this is the solution.

```
width = 20
py, vg = "Python", "Very Good"
print(f"{py:>{width}s} : {vg:>{width}s}")
```

Comment: Thank you.  This was exactly what I was looking for.  An additional question,  what is the purpose of the '>' in front of the variable?   I've seen others with '0' in front.  Is there a significance?

Comment: Actually, I just found my answer.  The '>' and '<' are for right alignment and left alignment of the number respectively.   Here's the source:  http://cis.bentley.edu/sandbox/wp-content/uploads/Documentation-on-f-strings.pdf

Answer (score 9):

```
print '%*s : %*s' % (width, 'Python', width, 'Very Good')
```

Comment: +1 This is better answer than mine. I was looking at ljust and rjust functions to do that.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to specify the widths at the same time, you can prepare a format string ahead of time, like you were doing - but with another substitution. We use `%%` to escape actual % signs in a string. We want to end up with `%20s` in our format string when the width is 20, so we use `%%%ds` and supply the width variable to substitute in there. The first two % signs become a literal %, and then %d is substituted with the variable.

Thus:

```
format_template = '%%%ds : %%%ds'
# later:
width = 20
formatter = format_template % (width, width)
# even later:
print formatter % ('Python', 'Very Good')
```

Comment: I like this as a way to dynamically generate format strings in general.  However, Mr. Hamidi's approach is better if only the field widths are to be dynamically interpolated.