# Fixed digits after decimal with f-strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, f-string

Is there an easy way with Python f-strings to fix the number of digits after the decimal point? (Specifically f-strings, not other string formatting options like .format or %)

For example, let's say I want to display 2 digits after the decimal place.

How do I do that? Let's say that

```
a = 10.1234
```

Answer (score 1450, accepted):

Include the type specifier in your format expression:

```
>>> a = 10.1234
>>> f'{a:.2f}'
'10.12'
```

Answer (score 309):

When it comes to `float` numbers, you can use [format specifiers](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#format-specifiers):

```
f'{value:{width}.{precision}}'
```

where:

- `value` is any expression that evaluates to a number
- `width` specifies the number of characters used in total to display, but if `value` needs more space than the width specifies then the additional space is used.
- `precision` indicates the number of characters used after the decimal point

What you are missing is the type specifier for your decimal value. In this [link](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language), you an find the available presentation types for floating point and decimal.

Here you have some examples, using the `f` (Fixed point) presentation type:

```
# notice that it adds spaces to reach the number of characters specified by width
In [1]: f'{1 + 3 * 1.5:10.3f}'
Out[1]: '     5.500'

# notice that it uses more characters than the ones specified in width
In [2]: f'{3000 + 3 ** (1 / 2):2.1f}' 
Out[2]: '3001.7'

In [3]: f'{1.2345 + 4 ** (1 / 2):9.6f}'
Out[3]: ' 3.234500'

# omitting width but providing precision will use the required characters to display the number with the the specified decimal places
In [4]: f'{1.2345 + 3 * 2:.3f}' 
Out[4]: '7.234'

# not specifying the format will display the number with as many digits as Python calculates
In [5]: f'{1.2345 + 3 * 0.5}'
Out[5]: '2.7344999999999997'
```

Comment: The dot should come before (not after) width, `f'{value:.{width}{precision}}'`

Answer (score 127):

Adding to Robᵩ's answer: in case you want to print rather large numbers, using thousand separators can be a great help (note the comma).

```
>>> f'{a*1000:,.2f}'
'10,123.40'
```

And in case you want to pad/use a fixed width, the width goes **before** the comma:

```
>>> f'{a*1000:20,.2f}'
'           10,123.40'
```

Answer (score 84):

Adding to Rob's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45310389/10908375), you can use format specifiers with *f strings* ([more here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/format)).

- You can control the **number of decimals**:

```
pi = 3.141592653589793238462643383279

print(f'The first 6 decimals of pi are {pi:.6f}.')
```

```
The first 6 decimals of pi are 3.141593.
```

- You can convert to **percentage**:

```
grade = 29/45

print(f'My grade rounded to 3 decimals is {grade:.3%}.')
```

```
My grade rounded to 3 decimals is 64.444%.
```

- You can do other things like print **constant length**:

```
from random import randint
for i in range(5):
    print(f'My money is {randint(0, 150):>3}$')
```

```
My money is 126$
My money is   7$
My money is 136$
My money is  15$
My money is  88$
```

- Or even print with a **comma thousand separator**:

```
print(f'I am worth {10000000000:,}$')
```

```
I am worth 10,000,000,000$
```

Answer (score 55):

Consider:

```
>>> number1 = 10.1234
>>> f'{number1:.2f}'
'10.12'
```

Syntax:

```
"{" [field_name] ["!" conversion] [":" format_spec] "}"
```

Explanation:

```
# Let's break it down...
#       [field_name]     => number1
#       ["!" conversion] => Not used
#       [format_spec]    => [.precision][type] 
#                        => .[2][f] => .2f  # where f means Fixed-point notation
```

---

Going further, Format strings have the below syntax. As you can see there is a lot more that can be done.

```
Syntax: "{" [field_name] ["!" conversion] [":" format_spec] "}"

# let's understand what each field means...
    field_name        ::=  arg_name ("." attribute_name | "[" element_index "]")*
    arg_name          ::=  [identifier | digit+]
    attribute_name    ::=  identifier
    element_index     ::=  digit+ | index_string
    index_string      ::=  <any source character except "]"> +
    conversion        ::=  "r" | "s" | "a"
    format_spec       ::=  [[fill]align][sign][#][0][width][grouping_option][.precision][type]

            # Looking at the underlying fields under format_spec...
            fill            ::=  <any character>
            align           ::=  "<" | ">" | "=" | "^"
            sign            ::=  "+" | "-" | " "
            width           ::=  digit+
            grouping_option ::=  "_" | ","
            precision       ::=  digit+
            type            ::=  "b" | "c" | "d" | "e" | "E" | "f" | "F" | "g" | "G" | "n" | "o" | "s" | "x" | "X" | "%"
```

---

Refer https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax

Answer (score 15):

It seems that no one use dynamic formatter. To use dynamic formatter, use:

```py
WIDTH = 7
PRECISION = 3
TYPE = "f"

v = 3
print(f"val = {v:{WIDTH}.{PRECISION}{TYPE}}")
```

Other format see: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language

---

Reference: Others [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36459595/11671779)

Answer (score 5):

Simply

```
a = 10.1234
print(f"{a:.1f}")
```

Output: 10.1

```
a = 10.1234
print(f"{a:.2f}")
```

Output: 10.12

```
a = 10.1234
print(f"{a:.3f}")
```

Output: 10.123

```
a = 10.1234
print(f"{a:.4f}")
```

Output: 10.1234

Just change the value after the decimal point sign which represent how may decimal point you want to print.

Answer (score 3):

```
a = 10.1234

print(f"{a:0.2f}")
```

in 0.2f:

- 0 is telling python to put no limit on the total number of digits to
  display
- .2 is saying that we want to take only 2 digits after decimal
  (the result will be same as a round() function)
- f is telling that it's a float number. If you forget f then it will just print 1 less digit after the decimal. In this case, it will be only 1 digit after the decimal.

A detailed video on f-string for numbers
https://youtu.be/RtKUsUTY6to?t=606

Answer (score 2):

To make monetary values more readable:

```py
>>> v = 12_093.74  # Currency value with minor currency digits
>>> f"{v:,.02f}"
'12,093.74'
```

See also the [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language).