# Seeking guide for Python3 new feature: "f-string"

Tags: python-3.x

How to use Python3 new feature : "f-string" to output the first 50 bits of math.pi?

We can achieve it by the following 2 old ways:
1 `("%.50f"% math.pi)`
2 `'{.50f}'.format(math.pi)`
But for the new feature "f-string",I knew that we can use this format:
f"the value of pi is {math.pi}", but how to limit and filter the first 50 bits?

```
In [2]: ("%.50f"%math.pi)
Out[2]: '3.14159265358979311599796346854418516159057617187500'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fixed digits after decimal with f-strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45310254/fixed-digits-after-decimal-with-f-strings)

Answer (score 0):

Same formatting as with `str.format`, but using the variable name in the first block before the `:`:

```
>>> import math
>>> f"{math.pi:.50f}"
'3.14159265358979311599796346854418516159057617187500'
>>> f"the value of pi is {math.pi:.50f}"
'the value of pi is 3.14159265358979311599796346854418516159057617187500'
```