# Python float to string, precision as variable

Tags: python, string

I want to convert a float like `a = 1.1234567` to a string, giving the precision as a second variable (which is why this is no duplicate of "Fixed digits after decimal with f-strings"):

```
def float2str(val, precision):
    ...

float2str(1.1234567, 3)  # '1.123'
float2str(1.1234567, 5)  # '1.12346' (mind correct rounding)
```

I know that f-strings can do the correct rounding using `f'{a:.5f}'`, but the precision has to be part of the string.

I came up with this horribly ugly solutions and hope someone can point me to a more elegant way:

```
f'%.{precision}f' % a
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fixed digits after decimal with f-strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45310254/fixed-digits-after-decimal-with-f-strings)

Comment: Why is `f'%.{precision}f' % a` a "horribly ugly solution"?

Comment: @Aryerez you're doing two string operations in that case, one to convert the precision to a string, then another that parses the precision out of a string and uses it to format the float...

Comment: @Aryerez a) It mixes two string formatting concepts, b) as Sam said you perform two formatting operations.

Comment: @MariusMucenicu No, this is no duplicate, please at least read the questions' first sentence, not only the heading.

Comment: How is this **not** a duplicate? it's exactly that question, you just have to replace the precision with a variable...if the answer there says `f'{a:.2f}'`, you just had to replace `2` with a variable, literally like the answer you accepted. The question doesn't have to be `1:1` identical to be the same, it's the same context.

Comment: My question obviously shows two things: 1. I know that f-strings can be used for fixed precision (which is the whole content of your duplicate candidate), which means that your suggestion did not provide anything not included in the question. 2. I didn't know that nesting was possible in f-strings to provide precision and value in one pair of braces. The accepted answer adds that second part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have a couple of options, given:

```
a = 1.1234567
b = 3
```

we can use either:

1. using format strings: `f'{a:.{b}f}'`
2. using old-style percent formatting: `'%.*f' % (b, a)`

Comment: Thanks, didn't think it would be possible to do nesting in f-strings.

Comment: https://pyformat.info/ contains lots of useful recipes like this, especially if you know one variant it helps for searching so you can translate between idioms