# Rounding float using f-string

Tags: python, string, multiline, f-string

Using %-formatting, I can round the number of decimal cases in a string:

```
pi = 3.14159265
print('pi = %0.2f' %pi)
```

And in output(in terminal) this would give me:

```
pi = 3.14
```

Can I use f-strings do this task? This feature has been added in Python 3.6

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fixed digits after decimal with f-strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45310254/fixed-digits-after-decimal-with-f-strings)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Include the type specifier in your format expression

format specifier:

```
f'{value:{width}.{precision}}'
```

example:

```
# Formatted string literals
x = 3.14159265
print(f'pi = {x:.2f}')
```

Comment: in latest 3.8 you can even ```pi = 3.14159265;
print(f'{pi =:.2f}') ```

Answer (score 6):

Yes. See the [Format Specification Mini-language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language):

```
>>> pi = 3.14159265
>>> print(f'{pi:.2f}')
3.14
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can do this. The code section would be

```
pi = 3.14159265
print(f"{pi:.2f}")
```

Output: 3.14

if you want to print 3 decimal point then

```
pi = 3.14159265
print(f"{pi:.3f}")
```

Output: 3.142

You can also use .format method to do this job.
like this:

```
pi = 3.14159265
print("{:.2f}".format(pi))
```

Output: 3.14