# How to use string formatting with f-string? I am getting an error here

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
print(f"PearsonR Corr Coefficient {%0.3f} {pearsonr_coefficient}")
```

Comment: *What* error? Give a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

With f-strings you have to specify the format in a different way:

```
print(f"PearsonR Corr Coefficient {pearsonr_coefficient:0.3f}")
```

Refer to [this guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) if you have more doubts.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
pearsonr_coefficient = 1.0545
print(f"PearsonR Corr Coefficient {pearsonr_coefficient:0.3f}")
# PearsonR Corr Coefficient 1.054
```

see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45310389/13124151)

The trick is here : **:0.3f**
Please check the [python documentation with examples](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals)

Answer (score 0):

`print(f"PearsonR Corr Coefficient {pearsonr_coefficient:0.3f}")`

Comment: Welcome to SO! You may want to explain why your answer resolves the question. Generally speaking answers that provide a solution to the question while also explaining the solution tend to score higher than those that simply provide a solution. Linking in relevant documentation also is a big help! Thanks for contributing!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer Here's some additional information on crafting an answer since I ran out of characters above :-)