# how do I limit my confidence level number to two decimal using python?

Tags: python, image, image-processing, deep-learning

I am writing confidence level using following code into my Image

```
 text1="color is {}".format(f'Class #{i + 1}-{class_names[ind]}-Confidence: {100 * conf}%')
```

how do I limit my confidence number to two decimal places rather than the 10 or so it gives?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fixed digits after decimal with f-strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45310254/fixed-digits-after-decimal-with-f-strings)

Comment: How about using the built in `round()` function? Read the documentation https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#round

Comment: I tried a couple of methods, unfortunately, they do not work.

Answer (score 0):

`f'{100 * conf:.2f}'` has to work