# python: percent format returning zeroes after the decimal place

Tags: python, format

I am trying to get some percentages to print to 4 decimal places.  My code looks like this

```
for i in range(len(candidates)):  #looping through the results
    percentage_votes = "{:.4%}".format(results[i][1] / voters)           #setting the number to a %
    print(f'{results[i][0]}: {percentage_votes} ({results[i][1]})')      #print result
```

When it prints; however, rather than giving me the decimal places of the division, it instead returns all zeros in the 4 decimal places.

```
Khan: 63.0000% (2218231)
Correy: 20.0000% (704200)
Li: 14.0000% (492940)
O'Tooley: 3.0000% (105630)
```

What do I need to correct in my code to give me the further divided number?  Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fixed digits after decimal with f-strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45310254/fixed-digits-after-decimal-with-f-strings)

Answer (score 0):

I tried this

```
"{:.4%}".format(3.4445453543)
```

**Output:** '344.4545%'

Which got me thinking that might be the division is not reporting float,

can you try this:

```
"{:.4%}".format(results[i][1] / float(voters))
```