# Issue with Floats? (probably super easy)

Tags: python

So I'm trying to round a float to two decimal places, which works fine if there's more, but otherwise breaks.

Anyways here's what I have:

```
    income=input("Enter your expected annual income in USD.")
    if floatcheck(income) == True:
        Income=float(income)
        income=str(round(Income, 2))
```

So I'm trying to either: always have it be two decimal places (which works fine if there is more than that, but if it is a whole number it will actually add a .0 which looks weird with currency), or have whole numbers not have any decimals at all. I tried a ton of different things like making it round to 3 and hoping that would add another 0, and adding +0.00
Oh, and I already defined floatcheck above as:

```
def floatcheck(str):
    try:
        float(str)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

Anyways I assume this is super easy to solve, but I cant seem to figure it out anywhere.

Comment: Rounding just changes the value of a float; it has no direct effect on how many decimal places are used to display that float.  You want `string formatting`, instead - `income = "%.2f" % Income` would be one way of writing this.

Comment: Don't use `float`s for currency, use either `int`s or `decimal`s, I suggest `decimal.Decimal`. There are serious issues with floating point arithmetic and currency (or any other fixed point number) in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html#floating-point-arithmetic-issues-and-limitations).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want formatted numbers, check out this explanation of [format specifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50340297/571215)

```
>>> num = 2
>>> f"{num:.2f}"
'2.00'
>>> num = 2.3455
>>> f"{num:.2f}"
'2.35'
```

Comment: Thank you! By changing this to: income=str(f"{Income:.2f}") it now works!

Answer (score 0):

Try using decimal and round as shown below. I have added float to look at it for comparison with the decimal function

```
    from decimal import *
    n = ['20','20.25','45','35','56.43','20.25','20.00','78.906']
    for i in n:
        print(round(float(i),2),'......',round(Decimal(i),2))
```

Output:

```
20.0 ...... 20.00
20.25 ...... 20.25
45.0 ...... 45.00
35.0 ...... 35.00
56.43 ...... 56.43
20.25 ...... 20.25
20.0 ...... 20.00
78.91 ...... 78.91
```

Comment: You shouldn't be passing `float`s to `Decimal`. You need to start with strings or ints

Comment: edited to pass it as a string to Decimal function

Comment: *no, not like this `Decimal(str(i))`*. The point is that the input needs to be in the form of a string. No floats.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Do you have an example where `Decimal(str(i))` goes wrong?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga It [seems to do pretty well](https://tio.run/##TYxLCsMwDET3PsXsYkOgTrsphex6j2ASpxXUHxQR6Oldkw9UuzdvRvkr7xRv98ylzJwCJj9ScB9QyIkFzx2VmhODQBHs4svrq7XmoVCPcOnRWbvBROxHQX/uNJktX8kNi/CfqFTlbjNTFH10WjRYFzTt8cyU8gM).

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode no,  but it relies fundamentally on an implementation detail which is the float-to-string conversion algorithm. The algorithm is chosen to produce the *shortest representation* that would allow an accurate "round trip". Previously, it used to jsut be "round to the 17th digit", now there's a smarter algorithm (I don't recall the name). The point is, this is an implementation detail.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Hmm, ok, I thought that that "shortest representation for roundtrip" is guaranteed by the specs, but I can't find it in the docs other than [in the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html), which I'm not sure counts as guarantee (don't know whether the tutorial uses "CPython implementation detail" boxes like the docs do elsewhere).

Answer (score 0):

Take the following example:

```
print(round(2.665, 2))
print(round(2.675, 2))

Output

2.67
2.67
```

**Note**: The behavior of `round()` for floats can be surprising. Notice `round(2.675, 2)` gives `2.67` instead of the expected `2.68`. This is not a bug: it's a result of the fact that most decimal fractions can't be represented exactly as a float.

When the decimal `2.675` is converted to a binary floating-point number, it's again replaced with a binary approximation, whose exact value is:

```
2.67499999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875
```

Due to this, it is rounded down to **2.67**.

If you're in a situation where precision is needed, consider using the decimal module, which is designed for floating-point arithmetic:

```
from decimal import Decimal

# normal float
income= 2.675
print(round(income, 2))

# using decimal.Decimal (passed float as string for precision)
income= Decimal('2.675')
print(round(income, 2))


Output

2.67
2.68
```

Comment: floats are also "designed for floating-point arithmetic", hence their name :-P