# Decimal point question how would I go about 9 decimal points

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am trying to get my answer to print out in 9 decimal points its currently printing over 100.  How do I fix this? I've tried using the round function unsuccessfully.

```
import math

def apply_interest(original_amount: float, interest_rate: float) -> float:
    return original_amount * (1.0 + interest_rate)


def compound_one_account(account_value: float, interest_rate: float, days: int) -> float:
    for day in range(days):
        print(f"Value is {account_value} on day {day}")
        account_value = apply_interest(account_value, interest_rate)


def compound_two_account(account_value: float, account_value2: float, interest_rate: float, days: int) -> float:
    total_account_value = account_value + account_value2
    for day in range(days):
        print(f"Value is {total_account_value,9} on day {day}")
        total_account_value = apply_interest(total_account_value, interest_rate)


compound_one_account(5000, 0.025, 5)
compound_two_account(2500, 2500, 0.025, 5)
```

Comment: in the f-string `{variable:.9f}`

Comment: In general, `f"Value: {value:.9f}"` would do that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fixed digits after decimal with f-strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45310254/fixed-digits-after-decimal-with-f-strings)