# How to convert a full number to 2 decimal places in python and mysql?

Tags: python, mysql, sql

So I have a whole number such as `45125` and want to convert to `451.25`, or `54200` to `542.00`. I want to be able to convert using both python and sql. Is there a way of doing it? I already tried researching but couldn't find a solution.

Comment: So you just want to divide all numbers by `100`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python,

```
print(format(54200/100, ".2f"))
```

In SQL,

```
SELECT
  CAST(54200/100 AS DECIMAL(7,2)) AS x;
```

Comment: thank you! this worked

Comment: Great, kindly approve and vote for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [format specifiers](https://peps.python.org/pep-0498/#format-specifiers) and f-strings in python and do

```py
newVal = 54200/100
print(f"{newVal:.2f}")
```

which outputs

```
542.00
```

The `2` in the print statement is the number of decimal places it displays.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45310254/fixed-digits-after-decimal-with-f-strings), which has excellent explanations.