# How replace number to parameter for space

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to change:

```
clk = "{:<48}{}".format(".clk", "(clk),")
```

to

```
clk = "{:<WIDTH_SPACE}{}".format(".clk", "(clk),")
```

where

```
WIDTH_SPACE=48
```

How can I do it ?

Comment: `clk = "{:<{width_space}}{}".format(".clk", "(clk),", width_space=WIDTH_SPACE)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Format string dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4302166/format-string-dynamically)

Answer (score 1):

You can specify `WIDTH_SPACE` in the format:

```
clk = "{:<{WIDTH_SPACE}}{}".format(".clk", "(clk),", WIDTH_SPACE=WIDTH_SPACE)
```

Comment: Just like mine tho

Answer (score 1):

Just use nested curly brackets, e.g:

```
clk = "{:<{WIDTH_SPACE}}{}".format(".clk", "(clk),", WIDTH_SPACE=48)
```

or even better use `f` strings:

```
WIDTH_SPACE = 48
text = 'clk'
clk = f".{text:<{WIDTH_SPACE - 1}}({text}),"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `format` with a specifier:

```
>>> clk = clk = "{:<{width_space}}{}".format(".clk", "(clk),", width_space=WIDTH_SPACE)
>>> clk
'.clk                                            (clk),'
>>>
```